# Global / Local View is returning view

Tags: 3d-view

When I use View > View Local/Global and I will returning to Global, it will also change my position of camera. It is so annoying. I want stay on same position without any change. Is there any script or something so that camera stay in position?

Comment: It just returns to the previous angle before you entered local view.

Comment: Yes I know, but it is very annoying, because I dont want change my view as before :) I want remain my current. I also looked to API python and Hotkeys there is not options for it. So maybe some custom script so I save my position and apply it after switch to Global.